# Throwing errors without curly brackets in lambdas/arrow-functions

Tags: node.js, lambda, promise, arrow-functions

Assuming I want to transform an error when using promises in NodeJs.

So for instance using [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) module in code underneath I'm trying to modify the error for a simpler one when making a `GET` for a certain URI.

```
const options = {
  'uri': uri,
  'headers': { 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8' }
}

rp.get(options)
  .catch(err => {
    throw {'statusCode': err.statusCode ? err.statusCode : 503}
  })
```

Is there anyway I can omit the curly brackets like we do when using `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) is a statement, so you cannot use it where an expression is required. The version of an arrow function with no curly braces expects an expression. You can return a rejected Promise instead of throwing:

```
rp.get(options)
  .catch(err => Promise.reject({'statusCode': err.statusCode ? err.statusCode : 503}));
```

Comment: Ya I knew about that but I'm not sure which one is better.

Comment: @chriptus13 They're the same. A thrown exception inside a Promise callback just gets converted into a rejected Promise using exactly this method. I like the syntax of `throw` slightly better, but not as a one liner.